# Как установить symfony на window 10?

Tags: php

Вот захотел установить *symfony* на винду. Но как то не получается . [Пытался установить как-то так](http://symfony.com/download#symfony1). Composer тоже пробовал, но командная строка не реагирует.

Comment: А что именно вы делали? Что именно не получилось? Какие ошибки получали от системы?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.